# How to add list of POJO to Firestore?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a class called `User` and i created a `List<User> users;`, Now i need to add this list to Firestore, What i did is that i iterated over the list and add every object separately as Firestore accept only HashMaps or objects and here is the code

```
for (User user:users){
            db.collection("Users").document(user.getUserNumber()).set(user)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                Log.e(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + task.getResult());
                            }else Log.e(TAG, "Error adding document", task.getException());
                        }
                    });
        }
```

My question is there is any way to add the whole list to Firestore with one request instead of calling the api as many times as the list size ??